# How to rename a file which seemingly has no name

Tags: command-line, files, rename, filename

I seem to have discovered a bug in Filezilla whereby a file with nonstandard characters its in name will, on copying to a different server, have no filename:

[image: Here's a screenshot]

The `"` is the file in question (for clarity's sake, it's a single character - not two apostrophes). How can I rename this file?

The solution must be able to be performed via the command line.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, the filename is `"`. As `"` is special to the shell, you need to escape it using any of the usual escaping manners.

You can do any one of the following, from the directory containing the file:

```
mv \" new_name
mv '"' new_name
```

Replace `new_name` with the actual name you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
mv ./\" newname
```

Or, if the " is the only single-character filename in your directory,

```
mv ./? newname
```

Comment: `?` matches any single character, not just `"`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even know if the file name is a single character -- for instance it might end in a blank, or several blanks.  Try

```
rm -i *
```

and say "n" to the removal, but it will list the full quoted name of the file, which you can then use in a mv command to rename it.